# Multiple fixed nods in d3

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to have many fixed nodes in this [graph](http://bl.ocks.org/2879486).

I tried the mashup codes from this [page](http://bl.ocks.org/1080941).

But it doesn't work.

```
     // Append text to Link edges
      var linkText = svgCanvas.selectAll(".gLink")
          .data(force.links())
        .append("text")
      .attr("font-family", "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
          if (d.target.x > d.source.x) { return (d.source.x + (d.target.x - d.source.x)/2); }
          else { return (d.target.x + (d.source.x - d.target.x)/2); }
      })
          .attr("y", function(d) {
          if (d.target.y > d.source.y) { return (d.source.y + (d.target.y - d.source.y)/2); }
          else { return (d.target.y + (d.source.y - d.target.y)/2); }
      })
      .attr("fill", "Maroon")
          .style("font", "normal 12px Arial")
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .text(function(d) { return d.linkName; });


  force.on("tick", function() {
    node[0].x = w / 2;
    node[0].y = h / 2;

    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  });
```

Nothing is displayed, just a blank page.
What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to append to the [enter selection](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-enter). Add `enter()` before `append("text")`.